# Grouping multiple matches with \str_case:nnF

Tags: xparse

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\demo}{m}{
\str_case:nnF{#1}
{
    {a} {Run case 1\\ % Actually super long code
    }
    {b} {Run case 1\\ % Actually super long code
    }

}
{
    % False code
 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \demo{a}
    \demo{b}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can define the "`b`" case without having to copy all of my "actually super long code"?

Comment: Note that there is no need to load `xparse` with a sufficiently new TeX distribution.

Comment: Why not define a variable that does "Run case 1"?

Comment: @gusbrs Because my "actually super long code" is actually some further `\IfValueTF` that performs test on optional arguments to `\demo` and that sound prone to error and too complicated :-)

Comment: @Clément Then a function, and pass said arguments...

Comment: @gusbrs Good thinking, and that's what's done in some of the answers below. I actually ended up … calling the function itself with the "other" argument, and that works perfectly well for my particular case.

Comment: @Clément Well, it is more convincing when you hear it from @ egreg.  ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Use a function that provides the very long code. It's recommended to use `\New(Expandable)DocumentCommand` just to parse the arguments and then to pass control to a function.

Whenever you have long code that's part of other code, it's best to make auxiliary functions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\demo}{m}
 {
  \clement_code_cases:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \clement_code_cases:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF{#1}
   {
    {a} { \__clement_code_superlong: }
    {b} { \__clement_code_superlong: }
    {c} { Simpler~code }
   }
   {
    False~code
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__clement_code_superlong: { Some~very~long~code }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\demo{a}

\demo{b}

\demo{c}

\demo{d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember to use `\cs_new_protected:(...)` when the code contains unexpandable functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very clean solution. It is elegant and extremely flexible. For my particular use case, I found something that I consider simpler, but your solution will most likely be useful in the future!

Answer (score 5):

Change `b` to `a` before testing

```
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\str_case:nnF{e}
\NewDocumentCommand{\demo}{m}{
\str_case:enF{
  \str_case:enF{#1}{
    {b}{a}
  }
  {#1}
}
{
    {a} {Run case 1\par % Actually super long code
    }

}
{
    % False code
 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \demo{a}
    \demo{b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very ingenious solution, that I really like. I manufactured something that I consider even simpler, but I really enjoyed your creativity and the simplicity of your solution!

Answer (score 4):

You could try regular expressions, such as in the following example (note that the order of the two first arguments is different between `\regex_match_case:nnF` and `\str_case:nnF`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\demo}{m}{
    \regex_match_case:nnF{
        {\A[ab]\Z} {Run case 1\\ % Actually super long code
        }
    }{#1}{
        % false code
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \demo{a}
    \demo{b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, strange syntax but that could work. Maybe a bit of an overkill since my two strings are simple, but ok. Where is the `\A[ab]\Z` syntax explained? I'm not familiar with it (my strings are 2 characters long).

Comment: @Clément It is not pure regex syntax, but `^[ab]$` would also work. The expl3 commands and the LaTeX3-style regex syntax are explained in the [LaTeX3 Interfaces PDF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). For regex syntax in general search the internet for "regular expressions".

Comment: `\A[ab]\Z` means: `\A` (or `^`) = start of string;  `\Z` (or `$`) = end of string; `[ab]` = one of `a` or `b`. If you need two-character strings, you could also use `(ab|cd|ef)` which would mean one of `ab` or `cd` or `ef` (add as many pipes as needed).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications and very ingenious solution. I found something that I consider simpler, but I'm sure your answer will be useful to other -- as of me, I learned about those regular expressions thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that I found was to call the macro again with the other argument, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\demo}{m}{
    \str_case:nnF{#1}
    {
        {a} {Run case 1\\ % Actually super long code
        }
        {b} {
            \demo{a}
        }
        
    }
    {
        % False code
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \demo{a}
    \demo{b}
\end{document}
```

It may be restricted to my particular use case, but it works fine.